# accessing html5 video elements using the api

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

trying to access various properties of my video tag. started looking at the HTML5 video api for some answers.

here is my basic code that i am playing with...

```
<body>
<div style="text-align:center">     
    <video id="video" onClick="cut()" src="test.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" >

        not supported
    </video>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myVideo=document.getElementById("video");
    var currentClip=0;
    document.write(myVideo.isEnabled); // trying to print this out to see what happens

    function cut()
      {
        if (currentClip == 0){
            myVideo.src = "bend.mp4"
            currentClip = 1;
            }
        else{
            myVideo.src = "test.mp4";
            currentClip = 0;
            }
      }

    function playPause(){
        if (myVideo.paused){ 
            myVideo.play(); 
        }
        else{ 
            myVideo.pause(); 
            } 
        }

     function makeBig(){ 
        myVideo.height=(myVideo.videoHeight*2); 
        } 

     function makeSmall(){ 
        myVideo.height=(myVideo.videoHeight/2); 
        } 

     function makeNormal(){ 
        myVideo.height=(myVideo.videoHeight); 
        } 

</script>
```

i am trying to use this line
    document.write(myVideo.isEnabled);
but get undefined. i have limeted experience in web programming, so please excuse if there are any obvious problems.

i seemed to think i could do this by reading this part section of the api
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#media-resources-with-multiple-media-tracks

i guess i just really don't know how to use it any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the `<video>` tag object does not have a `isEnabled` attribute.  You were looking at the `MultipleTrackList` interface which is not the same thing.
Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/video and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Also, instead of using document.write() to debug, use alert( something ) or better yet (if you are working on chrome or firefox with firebug install) use console.log( something ) and see the output in the console (use f12 in chrome to see it).